# how the object from the class to another activity and read from another activity

Tags: java, android

```
public void passData(){
Post post=new Post("title","name","25000");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
intent.putExtra("post", post);`
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one it very simple way to pass

```
public void passData(){
Post post=new Post("title","name","25000");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
intent.putExtra("post", new Gson().toJson(post));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

in another activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent()
Post post=Gson().fromJson(intent.getString("post"),Post.class);
```